# What's with all the errors?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, assembly-references

I have an WPF-MVVM solution with multiple service projects interconnected by a web of assembly references.  I'm using Visual Studio 2008.  My problem is that I constantly get errors telling me that methods and members do not exist in the current context.  When I recompile they go away.  What is going on?  Does anyone else have this problem?  Anyone have a solution? Its really annoying.  It becomes a problem when something referenced in XAML causes things to stop working until I compile my entire solution.

I have no circular references, and I'm doing everything by convention (no hacks).  Is this just something I have to deal with in VS 2008?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using Resharper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Service Pack 1, it might solve the problem. If that doesn't work, try isolating individual assemblies, until you find the problem (this might be time-consuming). It probably happens due to some sketchy XAML somewhere.

Comment: I already have Service Pack 1. I'm pretty sure its not sketchy XAML. I get errors in my back-end (C#) code as well. This is really annoying.

Comment: What I meant was that if you have an assembly (X) that contains XAML which is referenced by another assembly (Y), you might get C# errors in the referencing assembly (Y) because of Visual Studio thinking there's something wrong with the XAML in (X).

Comment: Seems, you are right. I'm hoping XAML will be much less of a stumbling block in 2010.  Thanks.